# How to display Range Apex chart when we have [start, end] are same at some time?

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

//Here @y:[start,end] at some point i have same start and end value but currently apex range chart don't show range bar when [start,end] is same value, but i need to show the bar for same [start,end] also how to do this?

```
var options = {
series: [
    {
        name: 'Bob',
        data: [
            {
                x: 'Design',
                y: [
                    4,4
                ]
            },
            {
                x: 'Code',
                y: [
                    5,7
                ]
            },
            {
                x: 'Code',
                y: [
                    0,1
                ]
            },
            {
                x: 'Test',
                y: [
                    10,10
                ]
            },
            {
                x: 'Test',
                y: [
                    4,4
                ]
            },
            {
                x: 'Validation',
                y: [
                    2,2
                ]
            },
            {
                x: 'Design',
                y: [
                    1,2
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [
            {
                x: 'Design',
                y: [
                    1,2
                ]
            },
            {
                x: 'Test',
                y: [
                    6,6
                ]
            },
            {
                x: 'Code',
                y: [
                    9,9
                ]
            },
            {
                x: 'Deployment',
                y: [
                    5,5
                ]
            },
            {
                x: 'Design',
                y: [
                    4,7
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Dan',
        data: [
            {
                x: 'Code',
                y: [
                    3,5
                ]
            },
            {
                x: 'Validation',
                y: [
                    3,3
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
],


  chart: {
        height: 450,
        type: 'rangeBar'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            horizontal: true,
            barHeight: '80%'
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10
    },
    stroke: {
        width: 1
    },
    fill: {
        type: 'solid',
        opacity: 0.6
    },
    legend: {
        position: 'top',
        horizontalAlign: 'left'
    }
```

//i need to show the bar for same [start,end] also how to do this?

//Please help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

For values ​​that have the same range, that is, the same start and end, you can add attributes to control the width and height of the bar, as well as the color, you also have to specify the value:

```
goals: [
          {
            value: 3,
            // strokeHeight: 10,
            strokeWidth: 3,
            strokeColor: "#FEB019"
          }
        ]
```

[Example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sara-wrp67u?file=/src/RangeBarSameStartAndEnd.jsx:2186-2346)

Useful apexcharts links:

- https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/column-charts/column-with-markers/
- https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/range-bar-chart/

[image]